# Set Value in Pandas MultiIndex Data Frame - View vs Copy

Tags: python, pandas

I have another question that has to do with confusion over whether Pands creates a view or a copy of a data frame. I've got a pretty simple example below. Can someone please explain to me how to change some subset of the values in a Pandas MultiIndex data frame?

```
arrays = [['bar', 'bar', 'baz', 'baz', 'foo', 'foo', 'qux', 'qux'],['one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two']]
tuples = list(zip(*arrays))
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=['first', 'second'])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(3, 8), index=['A', 'B', 'C'], columns=index)
new = [0,2] # want to slice 1st and 3rd rows
df.ix[new]['qux']['two'] = 2 #Doesn't actually set the value to 2
df.iloc[new]['qux']['two'] = 2 #This doesn't work either
df # returns original data frame
```

Comment: Have you read [Why does the assignment when using chained indexing fail](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#why-does-the-assignment-when-using-chained-indexing-fail)?

Comment: A note from [Jeff](http://stackoverflow.com/users/644898/jeff) in my now-deleted answer: `df.ix[new,('qux','two')] = 2`.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#advanced-indexing-with-hierarchical-index) is the documentation on indexing with a MultiIndex. Selecting has many possibilities, but it does not actually show how to set a single element (rather focusing more on setting via slicers to set more than one thing). So if you'd like to do a doc pull-request to update would be great.

You are indexing with labels and a slice, so  you can do this

We need to use `.ix` because we want the 0 an 2 to refer to *positions* rather than labels. The first term `[0,2]` slices the rows, the second `('qux','two')` slices the columns. The tuple syntax allows a multi-level specification.

```
df.ix[[0,2],('qux','two')] = 2

In [14]: df
Out[14]: 
first        bar                 baz                 foo                 qux         
second       one       two       one       two       one       two       one      two
A       1.018305 -1.435930 -1.200186  0.945463 -0.811409 -0.518572  0.083204  2.00000
B       0.699306  1.318884 -2.035644  0.069020  0.822584  1.085361 -0.615533 -0.37569
C       0.723708  2.008935 -0.014955  1.463080 -0.219143 -0.958606 -0.079401  2.00000
```